# Read value from variable

Tags: c

I am trying to assign a string or an int to msg to send it later to a server. This code is in the client.

```
  char msg[100];
    int a;
    .
    .
    .
      bzero (msg, 100);
      printf ("[client]your message: ");
      fflush (stdout);
      read (0, msg, 100);

      /* sending message to server */
      if (write (sd, msg, 100) <= 0)
        {
          perror ("[client]Error write() to server.\n");
          return errno;
        }
```

My question is how can I send the variable 'a', instead of writing a message from the command line.

Comment: At the moment, your variable `a` is undefined. But, once you've fixed that, you might try `itoa`.

Comment: It is defined in my code. My question is more, how can I send it instead of msg to the server. Because msg is read from the file descriptor 0, which is the command line. But I don't want that, I want it to be a simple predefined variable.

Comment: Depends on whether you want it sent binary, or as text.  The bigger question is, how will the server know which you sent?

Comment: As text works fine, can you show me an example?

The server knows because it will read the message.

Comment: `write()` just takes a `void *` as the second argument. You don't have to send an array.

Comment: Ok so, my program takes a message from my client, it stores it in 'msg' and sends it to the server through 'sd'. What I want to do is send a string from a variable, instead of the message written from the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're a little confused about what is going on in your program. First, let's start with [`write()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write).

The signature for the `write()` function is as follows:

```
ssize_t write(int fd,            // a file descriptor 
              const void *buf,   // a void * containing the payload
              size_t count       // the number of bytes of data to write
             );
```

So what you have right now is:

```
  read (0, msg, 100);  // read from stdin a ascii message up to 100 bytes

  /* sending message to server */
  if (write (sd, msg, 100) <= 0)  // write to a file descriptor (sd) the message
                                  // if it works, it should return the number of bytes
                                  // written
```

Now as far as I can tell, what you're saying is that you want to send the integer `a` instead of the char buffer `msg`. That's very easy to do:

```
int a = 0;
write(sd, &a, sizeof(a)); // send over the file descriptor "sd"
                          // you need a pointer for the second variable so use the &
                          // to get the address of a, then you need to identify
                          // the number of bytes to send, so use the sizeof macro
```

That will send a single integer over the socket.

You will likely need to be careful of endian issues using this approach for multibyte values (such as integers). From that perspective you might be better using an array of chars (shift in the values) so you know what to expect on the other end.

---

To be very blunt:

```
int a = rand();      // a random integer (assuming required headers and proper seeding)
char *msg = "Hello"; // a string

write(sd, &a, sizeof(a));       // write the integer
write(sd, msg, strlen(msg)+1);  // write a string (strlen + 1 for the null terminator)
```

Comment: And what if I want to send a string, instead of a simple integer? What I want to achieve is that my client sends first a number to the server, and then sends him a string after receiving an answer.

Comment: @user2995645 - well you're already doing that. `msg` is a string. So you would perform the `write()` as I've noted in my answer followed by the `write()` as you're currently doing in your question.

Comment: I know, but I don't want my string to be from stdin, I want it to be a variable.

Comment: @user2995645 - it doesn't have to be. Just hardcode `msg` (or whatever you want to call your string) as I did in my updated example, then send it. You just need a `void *` for the payload and a number of bytes and you can send anything... it doesn't have to be a specific type or from a specific source.

Comment: I know, but that's what I want to do. I want to generate a random number and send it to the server through my client. I can't know the number beforehand.

Comment: @user2995645 - gottcha. So did the updated answer explain it to you, or do you still have questions?

Answer (score 1):

```
sprintf(msg, "%d\n", a);
...
write(sd, msg, strlen(msg));
```

This assumes the client is expecting a string of digits (representing an integer) followed by a newline. I arbitrarly chose a newline delimiter, but you must have *some* convention by which the server knows what the heck you're sending.

Comment: +1 Agree about _some_ convention needed to indicate the end.  (I'd used '\0' and `strlen(msg)+1`.)